# Can we use passive without auxiliary verbs?

Tags: passive-voice

Can we use passive without auxiliary verbs like in below sentence just to stress on work rather than on point of time

"To maximize the process of the brain being washed properly and HGH being produce excellenty so you can create magic.

Comment: What do you mean by *se*? The example sentence is not a complete sentence. It's a noun phrase without a subject or verb. Something like *is [something]* has to be added to it. It's like only saying *Napkins.* Also, even as an incomplete sentence there are some components that make it ungrammatical. (For one, it should be *produced*, not *produce*.) And the use of *excellently* is odd. As is talking about *the brain being washed*.

Comment: Here's the key: to maximize the process of the brain being washed properly and HGH being produced excellenty so you expand your creativity, you need a healthy lifestyle.

Comment: @JasonBassford "se" was a misspelling of "we", it's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your direct question, which seems to be regarding whether you can use the passive voice in this way, yes, that is a valid way to use the passive voice. The things being referred to "the brain" and "HGH" are being acted on rather than taking the action themselves, which makes it passive. Some people recommend against using the passive voice in many cases, but it isn't ungrammatical.

That said, this sentence does not follow English grammatical rules in a couple of ways.

The first is that it is a sentence fragment. The revision you included in your comment where you add "you need a healthy lifestyle" fixes the problem because it provides a subject, which your first sentence lacked.

The second is that "being produce" doesn't match in tense. The right combination would be "being produced", which you got right in "being washed".

There is also a typo where you wrote "excellenty" instead of "excellently"

The final thing I want to point out isn't a grammar or spelling issue, but the phrase "brain washing" has a particular meaning in English, which is a process by which you influence the way someone else thinks. People who are drawn into organizations like cults can be said to be "brain washed", so you may want to avoid that turn of phrase. A better phrase could be "the process of the brain being cleaned out"

Comment: But it is not telling about the tense as no auxiliary verb has been use. Is it a general statement which is accepted as truth by the speaker.

Comment: "Being" already has an implied tense of an ongoing action, so you need to use "produced" to match that

Comment: 'Is being' not necessary? I mean only 'being' is used

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Using "is being" in place of "being" wouldn't change the meaning of the sentence, and wouldn't change the need to agree in tense by using "produced". "Is being produce" is still incorrect in this context